# Displaying composite model items in Razor View using Html.Display and Html.DisplayFor in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, foreach

I'm a little confused about this.
The ViewModel I'm passing over to the View Page contains two properties:

```
 public class UserProfileViewModel
{
    public ApplicationUser userProfile { get; set; }
    public AddressViewModel userAddress { get; set; }
}
```

The AddressViewModel itself contains a List, whose items I want the View Page to display:

```
public class AddressViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    ......
    public virtual List<GeoData> GeoDataList { get; set; }
}
```

Whew I try this on the Wiew Page

```
@model MySite.ViewModels.UserProfileViewModel
...
@foreach (var item in Model.userAddress.GeoDataList)
        {
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.PlaceName)
        </dd>
    }
```

I correctly get exptected results
But when I try to show the composite result that I need

```
@foreach (var item in Model.userAddress.GeoDataList)
        {
            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => (item.PlaceName + ", " + item.PostalCode + ", " + item.Latitude + ", " + item.Longitude))
            </dd>
        }
```

I get the following exception:

```
Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.
```

While when I try this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.userAddress.GeoDataList)
        {
            <dd>
                @Html.Display(item.PlaceName + ", " + item.PostalCode + ", " + item.Latitude + ", " + item.Longitude)
            </dd>
        }
```

I get no exception and no result at all (blank page).

Why is that?

Comment: Its just `<dd>@item.PlaceName, @item.PostalCode, ....` (or `<dd>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.PlaceName), @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.PostalCode), .... `

Comment: And you do not get an output with `@Html.Display(item.PlaceName + ", " + item.PostalCode ...` because you model does not contain a property with the same name that would be generated by concatenating those values

Answer (score 1):

you can use `@Html.Raw` which displays the result without any html encoding

```
@foreach (var item in Model.userAddress.GeoDataList)
        {
            <dd>
                @Html.Raw(item.PlaceName + ", " + item.PostalCode + ", " + item.Latitude + ", " + item.Longitude)
            </dd>
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Usman, first suggestion works while the second doesn't. Still wondering why with  @Html.Display(item.PlaceName) I get neither exception nor results.

Comment: You do not need `Html.Raw()` and the 2nd cannot work!

Comment: as stephen expained it in the comment @Html.Display works on model properties and here your string does not match any model

Answer (score 0):

You need display template for your GeoData class. Display template is a partial view called GeoData.cshtml in DisplayTemplates subfolder in your controller folder or Shared.

Your GeoData.cshtml will be something like

```
@model MySite.ViewModels.GeoData
@Model.PlaceName, @Model.PostalCode, @Model.Latitude, @Model.Longitude
```

And your UserProfile page code like

```
<dd>
     @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item)
</dd>
```